# Concurrency using worker group

Tags: go, concurrency

Trying to mock a cdn server worker using go channels and worker group patterns.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fileJobs := make(chan string)
    compress := make(chan CompressionStatus)
    upload := make(chan UploadResult)

// get list of files to distribute from a text file. This is usually 1-1.5 Gb, just filenames
    go listFiles("/Users/rverma/go/src/github.com/dsa/gopher/images.txt", fileJobs)
    go listFiles("/Users/rverma/go/src/github.com/dsa/gopher/videos.txt", fileJobs)

    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)
    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)
    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)
    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)
    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)
    go compressFile(fileJobs, compress)

    wg.Add(3)
    go uploadToAll(compress, upload, &wg)
    go uploadToAll(compress, upload, &wg)
    go uploadToAll(compress, upload, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
    close(fileJobs)
    close(compress)
    close(upload)
}

func listFiles(filename string, c chan<- string) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDONLY, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic("file not found")
    }
    defer file.Close()
    r := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for r.Scan() {
        c <- r.Text()
    }
}

type CompressionStatus struct {
    file       string
    compressed string
    status     bool
}

func compressFile(fileJob <-chan string, out chan<- CompressionStatus) {
    for fileName := range fileJob {
        fmt.Printf("compressing %s\n", fileName)
        fib(25) // calculate fibonnaci number, keep cpu busy
        fmt.Printf("compressed %s\n", fileName)
        out <- CompressionStatus{
            file:       fileName,
            compressed: fileName + ".compressed",
            status:     true,
        }
    }
}

func uploadToAll(comressedFile <-chan CompressionStatus, result chan<- UploadResult, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for fileName := range comressedFile {
        go func() {
            result <- US(fileName.compressed)
        }()
        go func() {
            result <- IND(fileName.compressed)
        }()
    }
    wg.Done()
}

type UploadResult string

type UploadServer func(region string) UploadResult

var (
    US  = fileUploader("US")
    IND = fileUploader("IND")
)

// can't change construct
func fileUploader(region string) UploadServer {
    sleep := time.Millisecond * 500
    if region == "IND" {
        sleep *= 4
    }
    return func(fileName string) UploadResult {
        fmt.Printf("uploading %s to server %s\n", fileName, region)
        time.Sleep(sleep)
        fmt.Printf("upload %s completed to server  %s\n", fileName, region)
        return UploadResult(region)
    }
}
```

Although the code works but when it finishes, it shows exceptions like. This seems to be an exception when we close the function which is receiving from the channel, while the loop which sending still active.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc00009a004)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x42
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc00009a004)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x64
main.main()
        /**/file_compressor.go:34 +0x2e1

goroutine 20 [chan receive]:
main.compressFile(0xc000074060, 0xc0000740c0)
        /**/file_compressor.go:75 +0x230
created by main.main
        /**/file_compressor.go:22 +0x13e
```

Bit confused what is the best way to address this. 
Also this is suppose to run on 8 core machine, i have added 6 go worker for compression as its cpu intensive process. Wondering if we can optimize this or make code bit cleaner.

Comment: Run `go vet` on the code to find this issue: the function literals in uploadToAll capture the loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compressFile` is waiting to read from `fileJob`, but there are no goroutines left that write to it. `uploadToAll` is also waiting from `compressedFile`, but that's not going to happen, so so `wg.Done` will not be called. Because of that, main goroutine is also waiting on `wg.Wait`. That means, all goroutines are waiting on something, and none of them are progressing, so deadlock.

One way to deal with this is to close the channel once you're done writing to it. That will terminate the for loops reading from the channel. Since you're writing to the same channel from multiple goroutines, you don't really know when you're done with it. You can add a new waitgroup for the `listFiles` goroutines, and wait for those two to complete, and then close the channel. Same for `compress` and `uploadAll` groups. You can do something like this:

```
wgList.Add(2)
go func() {
  wgList.Wait()
  close(fileJobs)
}()
go listFiles(&wgList,...)
...
```

Don't forget this:

```
func listFiles(wgList *sync.WaitGroup,...) {
  defer wgList.Done()
  ...
}
```

And similar, for the other groups...

Comment: how should i close the last upload channel, since I am not consuming its output. If I use above logic, the main function has only goroutines and it will stop immediately. I have to wait till all the uploads finished

Comment: You don't need to close channels unless you're using the close operation to signal another goroutine. If you need to wait until all uploads are finished, use a separate waitgroup to track the uploads, and wait for that in main.

Comment: got it, thanks, I have put the latest code here https://play.golang.org/p/mmpchvGwHAI. Do you see any optimizations/ better way of doing this, please suggest. Thanks again for quick help

Comment: @rohit Latest program still has closure on loop variable bug.  See "// <-- closure fix" comment in  https://play.golang.org/p/0SoE8Ekcmna for fix.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Can you please take a look, it seems the process is exiting before last few of files complete uploading step. https://play.golang.org/p/DPHIZb-vo6h, can't figure out what am I still missing.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for the comment, I read it was one of the classical beginners mistake. Thanks you soo much for your time and help. If you have any other feedbacks on code construct/flow etc, I am looking for constructive comments.